# Prevent undo of gojs picture

Tags: gojs

In my application, the user is able to use undo by clicking on a button that triggers `diagram.commandHandler.undo` Currently, a image is rendered into a gojs canvas. However, the image disappears when i use undo. I would like to prevent the user from using undo on it. What i've tried so far is using initiallayoutconpleted and etc but all mostly for nodes, which does not fit my use case. Currently, this is how i initialize the image on my canvas:

````
  diagram.add(GO(go.Part,
      layerName: "Background",
      selectable: false,
      pickable:false,
    }, GO(go.Picture, imagePath, {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      imageStretch: go.GraphObject.Uniform,
      imageAlignment: go.Spot.TopLeft
    })));

    diagram.model.commitTransaction("add bg"); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have an earlier call to **startTransaction**, don't you?

The problem is that the addition of the Part is recorded by the **UndoManager** and therefore is undone or redone.  I think you want to temporarily set **Diagram.skipsUndoManager** to true, add the background picture, and then set it back.

Another way of doing this:

```
myDiagram.commit(d => {
  d.add(...);
}, null);
```

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#commit

And yet a third possibility: add the Part to the "Grid" layer, for which **Layer.isTemporary** is true, so any changes in the layer are not recorded by the **UndoManager**. https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Layer.html#isTemporary

So just change the **layerName** to "Grid". I think you also need to set its **Part.position**. And then no transaction is needed.

Comment: Yes, i started a transaction beforehand. The solutions provided worked like a charm, thank you.